# Magento 1.9 Default Config theme package cached and can't find different theme

Tags: magento, caching, configuration, themes, multistore

When I change my "Default Config" store scope theme under Configuration>General>Design, it will only load the default them in default/default. Or it will load a theme I used to use. But, if I try to load my new custom theme package, it can't find it. Here are the details...

**Past:**
I was using a theme for my default config which worked fine. It was in `app/frontend/default/my_theme/` and `skin/frontend/default/my_theme/`.

In the Default Config General > Design tab, I had the following configuration:

```
Current Package Name: default/my_theme
```

The rest of the fields were blank. This loaded `my_theme` just fine.

**Present:**
Now I've created a multistore set up which now has 2 websites and 2 storeviews on each site. I decided to create a new theme package so I could have different "skins" for each website. I moved `my_theme` to:

```
app/design/frontend/my_theme/theme1/
skin/frontend/my_theme/theme1/
```

and

```
app/design/frontend/my_theme/theme2/
skin/frontend/my_theme/theme2/
```

I updated the Default Config store (the top-level global setting) under General > Design to:

```
Current Package Name: my_theme 
Translations: theme1
Templates: theme1
Skin (Images/CSS): theme1
Layout: theme1
Default: theme1
```

The 2nd website in my multistore has this configuration in General>Design:
Current Package Name: my_theme
Translations: theme2
Templates: theme2
Skin (Images/CSS): theme2
Layout: theme2
Default: theme2

**The Problem:**
The 2nd website finds `theme2` and loads it just fine, but my main website can't find `theme1`. It loads the default theme.

**Troubleshooting I've tried:**
Changing the 2nd website to load theme1 using the same set up as Default Config - the 2nd website finds and loads theme1 just fine.

Changing the main website configuration at the "website" and "storeview" level to bypass the default and use theme1 doesn't work either.

Renaming the folder of `my_theme`on the server to `new_theme`and then updating the Default Config>General>Design package `default/new_theme`doesn't even work. The only thing that works is `default/my_theme`!

Cleared all my cache in the admin panel, and deleted all files from `var/cache` on the server.

**Bottom line:**
It seems like somehow my site has cached `default/my_theme` and can only find that one. I can't update the Default Config theme package to anything else. The 2nd website loads in other themes fine, but it is the main website that can only load either the default theme or the old theme.

Comment: check system->design maybe there is a rule to overwrite the settings in system->configuration->design

Comment: Thanks Claudiu! There WAS an override rule in system>design to use default/my_theme on the Default Config store. I deleted that rule and everything is working great!